# Birational Equivalence

Tags: algebraic-geometry

On p.$12$ of Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry I", a rational map, say $\phi$, from the irreducible algebraic plane curve $X: f(x,y) = 0$ into the curve $Y : s^2 - p = 0$ is given by (where the terms are defined below): $$\phi(x,y) = (b(y/x)^2-4a(y/x)c(y/x),2a(y/x)x + b(y/x)).$$

$\textbf{For those wondering what each term in the map refers to}$:

Assume char$(k) \neq 2$.

The monomials of $f$ in $x,y$ have degrees $n-2, n-1, n$ only. Write $f = u_{n-2}+u_{n-1}+u_n$ where each $u_i$ is homogeneous.

Setting $y = tx$, it follows that $0 = x^{n-2}(a(t)x^2+b(t)x+c(t))$ where $a(t) = u_n(1,t), b(t) = u_{n-1}(1,t), c(t) = u_{n-2}(1,t).$

Setting $s = 2ax+b$ and $p = b^2-4ac$ gives $s^2-p = 0$ and hence the map $\phi$, constructed above, should be a rational map of $X$ into $Y$.

I follow that much but what I don't understand is why $\phi$ is necessarily a birational map. In the text up to this point, a birational map is a rational map with a rational map inverse. So, it seems that there is an inverse rational map but I don't see what it must be nor how to show that such a map exists.

Is there an easy way to see that $\phi$ is birational here?

Comment: Your setup is rather unclear - one thing which could help is defining your terms before using them. You might also want to try an example (and graph/draw it!) to see what's going on here - if you look at the right picture, you ought to get some good intuition.

Comment: @KReiser what terms need to be defined here? In the worst case scenario, you could open Shafarevich's book and find every term here within a couple of minutes.

Comment: Did you ever consider that not everyone has a copy of Shafarevich handy? When you assume something like that you immediately cut down your pool of potential answerers, which is something I'd think you want to avoid. To be specific about my complaint, every term in your equation of the map is defined after the map, which is not a great habit.

Comment: @KReiser note that I said "In the worst case scenario." I will edit the background statement.